# VBA : Fill a Listbox with an ArrayList

Tags: excel, vba, arraylist, userform

Does someone knows how can I add an `ArrayList` to a `ListBox` that is in a userform.
I've tried this code in the `UserForm1` module but it doesn't display anything when the `UserForm1` window is open.

```
Public Sub here()
Dim MyList As Object
Set MyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

MyList.Add "Item1"
MyList.Add "Item2"
MyList.Add "Item3"

UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList
End Sub
```

I've read some articles and I understood that I needed to activate `mscordlib.dll` Library but idk what else I can do to make it work.

**EDIT**

Here's the userform with the actual program :

[image: Nothing happens]

Comment: Just `UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList.ToArray`. You don't need to create a reference to the library because you are using `As Object` and `CreateObject(..)` aka *late binding*. If you want to use early binding, then after creating the reference, use `Dim Mylist As ArrayList: Set MyList = New ArrayList`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 i've just remove the reference that I've created and replaced the line ```UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList``` by your solution and it doesn't change anything... Is there a parameter in the initialisation of the Userform list that I've failed without minding to, idk

Comment: For more detailed information, read [VBA ArrayList – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/) by Paul Kelly.

Comment: I am afraid that you did not exactly do what @VBasic2008 suggested. You have to keep your code as it is, only use `UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList.ToArray` instead of `UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList`. Now, where the code you show exists? If inside UserForm1` cod module, you should use `Me.ListBox1.List`. If not, is the user form in discussion visible? Then, I do not see any button on the form. How to you run the code you show? If you want it running automatically you should place all the code in the Form `Initialize` event.

Comment: @FaneDuru the code is in the ```UserForm1``` module and I replaced the line : 
```UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList``` by ```UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList.ToArray``` and this doesn't work. Also the ```Me.ListBox1.List = MyList.ToArray``` doesn't work. The UserForm is visible and everything is initialized. Something else is that in another macro I have the same structure but with an ```array``` not an ```ArrayList``` and it works fine. I wanted to use the "flexibility" that those give.

Comment: **How do you run the code you show**? Place in the code, as its first line, `MsgBox "I'm running..."`. Do you see this message when the respective code runs?

Comment: @FaneDuru Ok I've learned from my mistake, running a code like this in a userform only calls the userform to be display but not the subfunction. When I'm in a sheet and I call ```UserForm1.Show``` it displays the userfom correctly. Nevertheless, the answer to the question was ```UserForm1.ListBox1.List = Mylist.ToArray```. Hope this post helps people who made the same mistakes as I did.

Comment: OK. As I said above, you may place this code in `UserForm_Initialize` event, or only a call to the respective procedure: `here`. And it will automatically run when the form is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me with the adjusted `MyList.Array`..

[image]

Like FaneDuru says, you need to trigger your sub in some way; in this case, I used the click event of the Userform. Only thing needed to show the 3 items was click the form et voila.
Usually, you'd want this linked to a button (click event of that) on the form or in the initialization of the userform, like so:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    here2
End Sub

Private Sub here2()
    Dim MyList As Object
    Set MyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    MyList.Add "Item1"
    MyList.Add "Item2"
    MyList.Add "Item3"
    MyList.Add "Yes!"
    
    UserForm1.ListBox1.List = MyList.ToArray
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Ty for your anwser it summurize well the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

### Populate a List Box With an Array List

**`UserForm1` Module**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ListBox1.List = GetListboxData
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```
Function GetListboxData() As Variant
    
    Dim MyList As Object: Set MyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    MyList.Add "Item1"
    MyList.Add "Item2"
    MyList.Add "Item3"
    
    GetListboxData = MyList.ToArray

End Function
    
Sub ShowForm()
    With New UserForm1
        .Show
        ' Continue with your code...
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect other answer thanks to you guys !